# interferometry vertical wavenumber

Tags: software-recommendations, matlab, synthetic-aperture-radar

I want to process a stack of Sentinel 1 SLC images (4) to produce tomographic layers for above ground biomass estimation. To do that, I need to generate the interferometric vertical wave number images for further processing.

Is there a software which can help me in this case>?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [SENTINEL-1 Toolbox](https://github.com/senbox-org/s1tbx) and follow the [tutorial](https://www.researchgate.net/file.PostFileLoader.html?id=575ea75193553ba70c47b6bd&assetKey=AS%3A372494465814528%401465821009260) hosted at research gate.